# Trying to connect to a REST API on my LAN using a C# program, but I get a WebException (Timeout). Telnet and browser works fine

Tags: networking, tcp, timeout, .net

I am running a very simple REST service using Flask on a Ubuntu Server on my local area network at home. I am trying to connect to this REST service using a simple .NET Core C# program. When I run the program it hangs and eventually throws a WebException (Timeout). If I try to connect to the same REST service using telnet or my web browser from the same computer, it works fine.

The exact same C# program + server works fine on the local area network at the office.

Things I have tried:

- Running Visual Studio with elevated privileges
- Running the app standalone with elevated privileges
- Disable *all* firewalls completely
- Disable Windows Defender on the client computer
- Run the REST server locally on Linux Subsystem in Windows -- exact same problems

I am at a complete loss here, and I am looking for suggestions for further troubleshooting to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried downloading [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/) ?
2. Then hitting the web service from another machine using it's private ip address using postman?
3. Post back the error you get, using the http status code.